# how to share a bean across modules in spring xd

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-xd

Lets say I want to create a stream with this defintion

`file | serviceActivator1 | transform | serviceActivator2`

So I have two custom modules in this definition. My understanding is that spring xd will create a child context of each component/module and deploy it in a container.

How can I share a single bean across serviceActivator1 and serviceActivator2. Basically this bean should be defined in the parent context, not the child context of each module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How to Add a Spring bean to the XD Container](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#How-to-Add-a-Spring-Bean-to-the-XD-Container). Bear in mind that the modules will only see the same bean instance if they are running in the same container.

You would also need a custom plugin to make the bean available to the modules.

However, it is generally better to share state between modules using message headers.